# Where to store shared data in FHS 3.0?

Tags: directory-structure, fhs

I'm working on a FHS2-conforming application that used to store data in `$sharedstatedir` (i.e. `$(prefix)/com`, e.g. `/usr/local/com`).

This directory [is no more](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) in FHS 3.0, and it seems that we need to start using either

- [**`/var/lib`**](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html), which should store

  > Variable state information

  or more verbosely,

  > state information pertaining to an application or the system. State information is data that programs modify while they run, and that pertains to one specific host.

  or
- [**`/var/local`**](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s02.html), which should store

  > Variable data for `/usr/local`

  (No more information is given about `/var/local`.)

Which one of these should we use?

Bonus question: Is there a variable for `/var/lib` / `/var/local`, similarly to `sharedstatedir` and friends that we should use, or should we simply hard-code the path into our makefiles?

Comment: RHEL converted `sharedstatedir` from `/usr/com` to `/var/lib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should choose `/var/lib`.

`/usr/com` does not exist in FHS 2.3 or FHS 3.  [FHS 2.3](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEUSRHIERARCHY) [FHS 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04.html)

`sharedstatedir` is a concept in [GNU autotools](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Installation-Directory-Variables.html) and [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)

GNU and freestandards.org do not always align.

The issue you mention came up in a [2006 mailing list post](http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-extras-list/2006-March/msg01549.html).  In the case of Red Hat, [the conclusion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=183370#c10) was to use `/var/lib`

Technically, if you're working on an open source project that defaults `prefix` to `/usr/local`, you could possibly use `/var/local`.  But I don't believe anybody does that in practice.  For one, note that `/var/local` is probably empty on your system.  For two, note that as soon as you or anybody running `./configure` changes `prefix` to `/usr`, you can't use `/var/local`, and the only remaining option is `/var/lib`.