# Moving to FHS 3: How to overwrite GNU Autotools directory variables?

Tags: variable, fhs, autoconf, automake, autotools

In GNU Autotools, the [directory variables `$sharedstatedir` and `$localstatedir`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) expand to `$(prefix)/com` and `$(prefix)/var` respectively.

However the `com` and `var` directories [don't exist anymore](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04.html) in FHS 3, and [`/var/lib`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html) should be used instead.

Therefore we want to overwrite `localstatedir` to `/var/lib` in our Autotools build system, since we're using it to define a macro in our code:

```
-DLOCAL_STATE_DIR=\\\"$localstatedir/program_name\\\"
```

But if the user provides a custom `localstatedir` with `--localstatedir=…`, we want to use that instead.

How can this be accomplished?

**Edit:**

So far I've managed to put a `localstatedir=/var/lib` to our `configure.ac`, which does the first part correctly. But I haven't found a way to redefine that later, e.g.
`./configure --localstatedir=/custom/dir`. Is this possible?

Comment: is this a duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213880/where-to-store-shared-data-in-fhs-3-0 ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, that's a different question, although related.